# WooCommerce Coupon field auto expand on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I try to auto-expand the coupon field on the WooCommerce checkout page. By default, the customer has to click "Do you have a coupon? Click here!". But we would like to have that field always visible. I tried with js but it is not working. However, I would like to have a pure PHP approach if this is possible.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_show_coupon', 99 );
function woocommerce_show_coupon() {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(\'.checkout_coupon\').show();
});
</script>
';
}
```

Does someone have an idea how I can do that in a smart way?

Cheers

Comment: you havent provided any screenshot or link to current page which is most importantly required to figure out what it is currently what changes can be tested it might be working with some theme but might break with your theme css codes kindly expose the page link you want changes into so it can be easy to debug issue

Answer (score 3):

```
//Adding CSS inline style to an existing CSS stylesheet
function mujuonly_add_inline_css() {

        $mustlogin_custom_css = "
               .woocommerce-form-coupon {
                  display:block !important;
               }
            ";

  //Add the above custom CSS via wp_add_inline_style
  wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce-inline', $mustlogin_custom_css ); //Pass the variable into the main style sheet ID

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mujuonly_add_inline_css' ); //Enqueue the CSS style
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not expand the coupon box. Does it work in your system?

Comment: This always shows the coupon form expanded. Tested OK with storefront theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-coupon.php the code below:

```
if ( ! wc_coupons_enabled() ) { // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
    return;
}

?>

<form class="checkout_coupon woocommerce-form-coupon" method="post" style="display:block">

    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'If you have a coupon code, please apply it below.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="coupon_code" class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <button type="submit" class="button<?php echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); ?>" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this does not expand the coupon box. Does it work in your system?